# Store images and labels to hdf5 files

Tags: pytorch, hdf5

I have a folder of images and a csv file with a label corresponding to each image. I am trying to train a pytorch model, the problem is data loading seems to be a bottleneck,so i want to store the images to a HDf5 file and read them.

Comment: How are you currently loading image data? Why do you think loading the same data from HDF5 will be any faster?

Comment: @kcw78 currently im just loading with pillow-simd and converting them to pytorch tensors, for the second question i am not really sure, but ive heard that hdf5 will be faster

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: I work with HDF5 a lot, but not an image data expert. Others have used HDF5 with ML. For example, the SVHN data set was saved in HDF5 format (from Matlab). HDF5 has good I/O performance. Speed improvements depend on current method vs HDF5. How are you currently loading the data?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the number of workers in your DataLoader? Also looking at [this discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-speed-up-the-data-loader/13740/6) it appears that hdf5 may have concurrency issues.

Comment: Yes my i have been playing around with the number of number of workers from 8-12, but the gpu still remains idle for some time.